# Play framework app 'cannot find template' while deployed on heroku

Tags: exception, heroku, playframework

i have written an app that runs locally with no issues

after deploying app to Heroku when trying to enter a certain page i receive the following error (taken from log):

> - 2012-02-29T00:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]: Internal Server Error (500) for request GET /Application/adminPage
> - 2012-02-29T00:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]: Template not found (In /app/controllers/Application.java around line 78)
> - 2012-02-29T00:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:
> - 2012-02-29T00:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.mvc.Controller.renderTemplate(Controller.java:667)
> - 2012-02-29T00:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]:
> - 2012-02-29T00:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]: play.exceptions.TemplateNotFoundException: Template not found : Application/admin.html
>     2012-02-29T00:11:53+00:00 app[web.1]: The template Application/admin.html does not exist.

/app/controllers/Application.java around line 78 :

```
public static void admin(){
       List<MailUSer> allUsers =  MailUSer.findAll();
        render(allUsers);
}
```

rout file:

```
# Home page
GET     /          Application.index
GET   /            module:secure
POST  /Register/welcome              Register.welcome
GET /Application/adminPage             Application.admin

# Ignore favicon requests
GET     /favicon.ico                            404

# Map static resources from the /app/public folder to the /public path
GET     /public/                                staticDir:public

# Catch all


*       /{controller}/{action}                  {controller}.{action}
```

what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: When i first created the Admin.html file i did it with capital A but changed it pretty quick to small a then uploaded to heroku and exception was still there, in the end i created a new file admin2.html sent render to it and it seemed to solve issue, i guess for some reason play was seeing the old file name.. still don't know what was wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had this problem on Heroku, and it was case-insensitivity.

In my controller, I had something like

```
public static void showUser(Long id) {
    ...
    render(user);
}
```

but in my views folder I had

```
app/views/Application/showuser.html
```

On my Mac, and Windows machine, this is fine, but on Linux machines, including Heroku, the file `showUser.html` will not be found.

Answer (score 4):

try to troubleshoot using the following items:

1. did you upload the views folder under app to the Heroku?
2. do you have case sensitive problems in your file and directory names (say `Application/admin.html` is different from `application/admin.html` etc)? When you are in a windows platform this is okay, but when you deloy app to a linux/unix environment, this going to break your app.

BTW, `MailUSer` looks strange, why not `MailUser` ?

Comment: uploaded folders as usual including view. don't think i have case sensitive issue - i even changed `render(allUsers);` to `renderTemplate("Application/admin.html",allUsers);` how can i check my deployed files on heroku ? thanks [regarding MailUSer sorry it was a typo]